# Docx4j buffered image

Tags: java, drawing, bufferedimage, docx4j

I am using docx4j to manipulate docx. What im trying to do is make buffered image of every image in all tables. I have instance of org.docx4j.wml.Drawing, is there any way to make buffered image from it?

Source codes are mostly downloaded from somewhere.

Only relevant parts:

```
 for (Object o : children ) {                   
            System.out.println("  " + o.getClass().getName() );
            if ( o instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {
                System.out.println("      " +  ((JAXBElement)o).getName() );
                System.out.println("      " +  ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName());

                // TODO - unmarshall directly to Text.
                if ( ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Text") ) {
                    org.docx4j.wml.Text t = (org.docx4j.wml.Text)((JAXBElement)o).getValue();
                    System.out.println("      " +  t.getValue() );


                } else if ( ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Drawing") ) {
                    org.docx4j.wml.Drawing d   = (org.docx4j.wml.Drawing)((JAXBElement)o).getValue();
                    describeDrawing(d);


                }
```

this will basically go thru cells in table and determine wherther its a text or a picture

I want to make bufferedimages from pictures.

Complete source codes:

```
 import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import org.docx4j.dml.picture.Pic;
import org.docx4j.dml.wordprocessingDrawing.Anchor;
import org.docx4j.dml.wordprocessingDrawing.Inline;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.SaveToZipFile;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.Body;



public class Test {

    public static JAXBContext context = org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.jc; 

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private static WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //String inputfilepath = "/home/dev/workspace/docx4j/sample-docs/jpeg.docx";
        String inputfilepath = "C:\\Users\\Blizzard\\Desktop\\VSE\\15.docx";

        boolean save = false;
        String outputfilepath = "C:\\Users\\Blizzard\\Desktop\\VSE\\112.docx";  


        // Open a document from the file system
        // 1. Load the Package
        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));

        // 2. Fetch the document part       
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        // Display its contents 
        System.out.println( "\n\n OUTPUT " );
        System.out.println( "====== \n\n " );   

        org.docx4j.wml.Document wmlDocumentEl = (org.docx4j.wml.Document)documentPart.getJaxbElement();
        Body body =  wmlDocumentEl.getBody();

        List <Object> bodyChildren = body.getEGBlockLevelElts();

        walkJAXBElements(bodyChildren);         

        // Save it

        if (save) {     
            SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(wordMLPackage);
            saver.save(outputfilepath);
        }
    }

    static void walkJAXBElements(List <Object> bodyChildren){

        for (Object o : bodyChildren ) {

            if ( o instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {

                System.out.println( o.getClass().getName() );
                System.out.println( ((JAXBElement)o).getName() );
                System.out.println( ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName() + "\n\n");

                if ( ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Tbl") ) {
                    org.docx4j.wml.Tbl tbl = (org.docx4j.wml.Tbl)((JAXBElement)o).getValue();
                    describeTable(tbl);
                }
            } else if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.P) {
                System.out.println( "Paragraph object: ");

                if (((org.docx4j.wml.P)o).getPPr() != null
                        && ((org.docx4j.wml.P)o).getPPr().getRPr() != null
                        && ((org.docx4j.wml.P)o).getPPr().getRPr().getB() !=null) {
                    System.out.println( "For a ParaRPr bold!");
                }


                walkList( ((org.docx4j.wml.P)o).getParagraphContent());
            }
        }
    }

    static void walkList(List children){

        for (Object o : children ) {                    
            System.out.println("  " + o.getClass().getName() );
            if ( o instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {
                System.out.println("      " +  ((JAXBElement)o).getName() );
                System.out.println("      " +  ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName());

                // TODO - unmarshall directly to Text.
                if ( ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Text") ) {
                    org.docx4j.wml.Text t = (org.docx4j.wml.Text)((JAXBElement)o).getValue();
                    System.out.println("      " +  t.getValue() );


                } else if ( ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Drawing") ) {
                    org.docx4j.wml.Drawing d   = (org.docx4j.wml.Drawing)((JAXBElement)o).getValue();
                    String relation = describeDrawing(d);


                }



            } else if (o instanceof org.w3c.dom.Node) {
                System.out.println(" IGNORED " + ((org.w3c.dom.Node)o).getNodeName() );                 
            } else if ( o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.R) {
                org.docx4j.wml.R  run = (org.docx4j.wml.R)o;
                if (run.getRPr()!=null) {
                    System.out.println("      " +   "Properties...");
                    if (run.getRPr().getB()!=null) {
                        System.out.println("      " +   "B not null ");                     
                        System.out.println("      " +   "--> " + run.getRPr().getB().isVal() );
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("      " +   "B null.");                                             
                    }
                }
                walkList(run.getRunContent());              

            } else {

                System.out.println(" IGNORED " + o.getClass().getName() );

            }
//          else if ( o instanceof org.docx4j.jaxb.document.Text) {
//              org.docx4j.jaxb.document.Text  t = (org.docx4j.jaxb.document.Text)o;
//              System.out.println("      " +  t.getValue() );                  
//          }
        }
    }

    static void describeTable( org.docx4j.wml.Tbl tbl ) {

        // What does a table look like?
        boolean suppressDeclaration = false;
        boolean prettyprint = true;
        System.out.println( org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(tbl, suppressDeclaration, prettyprint) );

        // Could get the TblPr if we wanted them
         org.docx4j.wml.TblPr tblPr = tbl.getTblPr();

         // Could get the TblGrid if we wanted it
         org.docx4j.wml.TblGrid tblGrid = tbl.getTblGrid();

         // But here, let's look at the table contents
         for (Object o : tbl.getEGContentRowContent() ) {

             if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Tr) {

                 org.docx4j.wml.Tr tr = (org.docx4j.wml.Tr)o;

                 for (Object o2 : tr.getEGContentCellContent() ) {

                        System.out.println("  " + o2.getClass().getName() );
                        if ( o2 instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {

                            if ( ((JAXBElement)o2).getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Tc") ) {
                                org.docx4j.wml.Tc tc = (org.docx4j.wml.Tc)((JAXBElement)o2).getValue();

                                // Look at the paragraphs in the tc
                                walkJAXBElements( tc.getEGBlockLevelElts() );

                            } 

                            else {
                                // What is it, if it isn't a Tc?
                                System.out.println("      " +  ((JAXBElement)o).getName() );
                                System.out.println("      " +  ((JAXBElement)o).getDeclaredType().getName());
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("A  " + o.getClass().getName() );                            
                        }

                 }


             } else {
                System.out.println("C  " + o.getClass().getName() );
             }

         }



    }

    static String describeDrawing( org.docx4j.wml.Drawing d ) {

        System.out.println(" describeDrawing " );
        String vrat = null;
        if ( d.getAnchorOrInline().get(0) instanceof Anchor ) {

            System.out.println(" ENCOUNTERED w:drawing/wp:anchor " );
            // That's all for now...

        } else if ( d.getAnchorOrInline().get(0) instanceof Inline ) {

            // Extract w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/pic:pic/pic:blipFill/a:blip/@r:embed

            Inline inline = (Inline )d.getAnchorOrInline().get(0);

            Pic pic = inline.getGraphic().getGraphicData().getPic();

            //pic.

            vrat = pic.getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().getName();

            System.out.println( "image name: " +   vrat);
            //bordel(inline);



        } else {

            System.out.println(" Didn't get Inline :(  How to handle " + d.getAnchorOrInline().get(0).getClass().getName() );
        }
        return vrat;
    }



}
```

I tried adding some methods and im getting rly desperate:

```
private static void bordel(org.docx4j.wml.Drawing d){
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
        RelationshipsPart relsPart = documentPart.getRelationshipsPart();
        Relationships rels = relsPart.getRelationships();
        List<Relationship> relsList = rels.getRelationship();

        for (Relationship r : relsList) {

            JAXBElement el = printInfo(relsPart.getPart(r));
            if (el != null) {

                   if ( el.getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Drawing") ) {


                        org.docx4j.wml.Drawing c   = (org.docx4j.wml.Drawing) el.getValue();
                        if (c.equals(d)){
                            System.out.println( "I found part");
                        }


                    }
             }



        }           
    }
```

this method is called on every image in cell and attemps to find Part which i believe i can convert to bufferedimage

but next method converting Part to JAXBElement always returns null

```
public static JAXBElement printInfo(Part p) {

        JAXBElement el = null;


        if (p instanceof JaxbXmlPart) {

            Object o = ((JaxbXmlPart)p).getJaxbElement();

            if (o instanceof javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) {
                //sb.append(" containing JaxbElement:" + XmlUtils.JAXBElementDebug((JAXBElement)o) );
                el= (JAXBElement) o;
            } else {
                //sb.append(" containing JaxbElement:"  + o.getClass().getName() );
            }
        }

        return el;
    }
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of code.  I doubt many will read it.  Could you reduce it to relevant parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will find the image relationships for you:

```
    BlipFinder bf = new BlipFinder();
    new TraversalUtil(paragraphs, bf);

    for (CTBlip imageReference : bf.blips) {

        if (imageReference.getLink() != null
                && !imageReference.getLink().equals("")) {

            Relationship existingRel = docxPkg.getMainDocumentPart()
                    .getRelationshipsPart().getRelationshipByID(
                            imageReference.getLink());

            :

        } else if (imageReference.getEmbed() != null) {

            String relId = imageReference.getEmbed();

            Relationship r = docxPkg.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart().getRelationshipByID(relId);
            if (r.getTargetMode()!=null 
                    && r.getTargetMode().toLowerCase().equals("external")) {
                :

            } else {

                BinaryPartAbstractImage oldPart = (BinaryPartAbstractImage)docxPkg.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart().getPart(relId);

                : 

            }

        } else {
            log.error("HELP! neither linked nor embedded?");
        }

    }
}

    static class BlipFinder extends CallbackImpl {

        List<CTBlip> blips = new ArrayList<CTBlip>();  

        @Override
        public List<Object> apply(Object o) {

            if (o instanceof CTBlip)
                blips.add((CTBlip)o);

            return null;
        }
```

and in the indicated case, give you a BinaryPartAbstractImage.  Once you have that, you can do whatever you like...

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, I didnt expect someone to actually bother with it, thank you very much!

Comment: I used this to get BufferedImage

BufferedImage a = (BufferedImage) ImageIO.createImageInputStream(oldPart);

is that correct?

Comment: No, but oldPart.getBuffer() returns a ByteBuffer